# Using custom folder icon for storage access framework doesn't show

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I have implemented a SAF DocumentsProvider. I have a custom icon for use in my queryRoots() call, which works as expected (the custom icon shows up in the root of the file chooser). However, I also designate a custom icon in queryChildDocuments when the child is a folder like this (many items removed for brevity):

```
    final MatrixCursor.RowBuilder row = cursor.newRow();
    try {
        *
        *
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_ICON, R.drawable.media_folder);
        row.add(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_MIME_TYPE, DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR);
        *
        *
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.d("Lifecycle: exception processing folder metadata: %s", e.getMessage());
    }
```

The default folder icon shows up for each directory entry instead of my custom icon. It is almost as if once it is designated a MIME_TYPE_DIR then any custom icon is ignored and the default folder icon is used?

Answer (score 1):

> It is almost as if once it is designated a MIME_TYPE_DIR then any custom icon is ignored and the default folder icon is used?

Yes, all folders will use the folder icon. There is no ability to customize the icon for folders, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ian. Btw, I posted an enhancement request on Buganizer: https://issuetracker.google.com/162569130  - it has to do with providing a mechanism for the provider to signal to the framework that they need to gather doc info in "pages". This is the case, for example, if I'm working with a directory with 1000's of files, and I need to present them to the user a page at a time. Would be curious what you think.